# What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests

I'm using the python [`requests` module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) to send a RESTful GET to a server, for which I get a response in JSON. The JSON response is basically just a list of lists.

What's the best way to coerce the response to a native Python object so I can either iterate or print it out using `pprint`?

Answer (score 444, accepted):

You can use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get(...)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

This converts a given string into a dictionary which allows you to access your JSON data easily within your code.

Or you can use @Martijn's helpful suggestion, and the higher voted answer, `response.json()`.

Comment: ok great, however each of the elements would still be unicode.

Comment: @felix001: yes, although you can convert any data using `str()`. On the other hand unicode data isn't bad to have around (in preparation for the future).

Comment: Much, much better to use `response.json()`, as it'll do a *better job* of figuring out the encoding used. (Disclaimer, I wrote some of that code).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: then how can I use requests json parser later on a memcached text of the response? i.e. having the output of `response.text()`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, found: `requests.compat.json.loads(resp_text)`

Comment: @neurino you want the standard library [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). The `requests.compat` module is there to bridge different Python versions and `requests.compat.json` is the same thing as `json` on practically every system you’d care about.

Comment: Is there a better library to use, because response.json() seems to result in a data structure about 10x the size of the JSON.  Why is it so big?  Is it the overhead of all the contained objects?

Comment: it is worked for my case
`res = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_classes')
     json_data = json.loads(res.text)
     print(json_data)`

Answer (score 724):

Since you're using `requests`, you should use the response's [`json`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method.

```
import requests

response = requests.get(...)
data = response.json()
```

It [autodetects which decoder to use](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/4ea09e49f7d518d365e7c6f7ff6ed9ca70d6ec2e/requests/models.py#L868-L892).

Comment: Just keep in mind that it have appeared somewhere in between v0.12 and v1.0 so that for example Ubuntu 12.04 deb-package for python-requests does not have this function yet (it is v0.8).
You can `pip install requests` though instead of using deb package.

Comment: I am a little curious what is now `data` is it a list of list or a dictionary.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza `data` mirrors the structure of the JSON it's reading. For example, if the response is: `[{"a": {...}}]`, `data` is a list, with `list[0] == {'a': {...}}`. If the response is `{"a": "b", "c": "d"}`, `data` is a dict. Does that answer your question?

Comment: this approach is essentially the same as the json.loads(response) approach in other answers, with the exception that the latter may be easier to tab through if you're using a Jupyter environment

Comment: shouldn't it be `data = response.json`? Otherwise, I get `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: @CGFoX what version are you running? I'm still seeing the API work the same way on the latest version: ```>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
>>> r.json
<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
>>> r.json()
{'args': {}, ...}```

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7, but I don't think that's the issue. See [this thread with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31481487/2745116)

Comment: @CGFoX that is the _request_ object, not the _response_. The response JSON needs to be parsed, which is why it is a method.

Comment: Upvote for this because I was usually using the json.loads(response.text) method until on some large jsons I found that using respons.json() was much faster than the other way.

Comment: @pswaminathan what a fantastic answer! This saved me a lot of headache. Was using the response.text which was messing this up. Thanks again :)

Comment: Even with this method, I get an 'invalid control character' JSONDecodeError. Any insight into this, @Martijn Pieters?

Comment: @sFishman: this method nor any other can't protect you from invalid JSON data. I can't tell you how to fix your problem because there could be any number of reasons you are fetching data that can't be decoded as JSON.

Comment: does calling response.json() multime times do the parsing again and again?

Answer (score 36):

You can use the json response as dictionary directly:

```py
import requests

res = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
print(f'Total users: {res.json().get("total")}')
```

or you can hold the json content as dictionary:

```py
json_res = res.json()
```

and from this `json_res` dictionary variable, you can extract any value of your choice

```py
json_res.get('total')
json_res["total"]
```

**Attentions** Because this is a dictionary, you should keep your eye on the key spelling and the case, *i.e. 'total' is not the same as 'Total'*

Comment: json().get() ist the part I was looking for - for half an hour. Thank you!

Comment: @ESP32 The incoming response could be a list. It should be noted.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?

The top answers show *seemingly* two different ways to parse a json response into a Python object but they are essentially the same.

`response.json()` differs in two places:

- it uses `simplejson` (which is [the externally maintained development version of the json library included with Python](https://pypi.org/project/simplejson/)) if it's installed in your environment, but uses the built-in `json` if not ([source](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/eea3bbf9ac635f465ee6c9903dc57c677952dafd/src/requests/compat.py#L31-L37)). I think there used to be a performance difference between `json` and `simplejson` in the past (when Python 2 was still widely used) but there's almost no difference between the libraries anymore.
- if the response doesn't have an encoding (`response.encoding` is None), then it tries to guess it and try to decode using the guessed encoding ([source](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/eea3bbf9ac635f465ee6c9903dc57c677952dafd/src/requests/models.py#L955-L958)).

So in 99.9999% of cases, `response.json()` and `json.loads(response.text)` will produce the same dictionary. It may differ if the source json has some weird encoding.