# "dict object is not callable" when trying to get value from request.json

Tags: python, json, flask

I am getting the user location with JavaScript and sending the latitude and longitude to the Flask app.  However, I get `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` when I try to get the latitude from `request.json`.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
@app.route('/location', methods = ['POST'])
def location():
    latitude = request.json('latitude')
    longitude = request.json('longitude')
    send_email("myemail@example.com","Location:",str(latitude) + str(longitude))
```

```javascript
function showPosition(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/location',
    data: JSON.stringify({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to add an argument to your location() function to accept the JSON data.

Comment: What should it be? @Chris

Comment: Woops I was wrong, I'm posting an answer with the correct solution.

Comment: PLease Post it Thank you @Chris :)

Comment: IMO this is incorrectly marked as a duplicate, because the subject is not specifically about accessing a dictionary, rather the real behaviour of `request.json`. If you look at the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) it appears as if the `json` property is in fact callable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to replace the `()` with `[]` as such:

```
latitude = request.json['latitude']
```

The `request.json` object is a dictionary, not a function.