# Can't extract JSON from an http request

Tags: python, json

I'm having problems getting data from an HTTP response.  The format unfortunately comes back with '\n' attached to all the key/value pairs.  JSON says it must be a str and not "bytes".

I have tried a number of fixes so my list of includes might look weird/redundant.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import requests

url = "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ,AAPL"
response = urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
print(content)

data = json.loads(content)
info = data[0]
print(info)
#got this far - planning to extract "id:" "22144"
```

Comment: You include requests [use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/parsing-json-responses) it!

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to making requests in Python, I personally like to use the `requests` library. I find it easier to use.

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ,AAPL')
json_obj = json.loads(r.text[4:])

print(json_obj[0].get('id'))
```

The above solution prints: `22144`

The response data had a couple unnecessary characters at the head, which is why I am only loading the relevant (json) portion of the response: `r.text[4:]`. This is the reason why you couldn't load it as json initially.

Comment: yep, the forward slashes were messing up the json decoding.

Comment: Using r.json() will throw an error because the response has forward slashes at the beginning (invalid json format) , as @deweyredman mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Bytes object has method `decode()` which converts bytes to string. Checking the response in the browser, seems there are some extra characters at the beginning of the string that needs to be removed (a line feed character, followed by two slashes: '\n//'). To skip the first three characters from the string returned by the `decode()` method we add `[3:]` after the method call.

```
data = json.loads(content.decode()[3:])
print(data[0]['id'])
```

The output is exactly what you expect:

```
22144
```

Answer (score -1):

> JSON says it must be a str and not "bytes".

Your content is "bytes", and you can do this as below.

```
data = json.loads(content.decode())
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Sorry, Google is unreachable in China. I mean, a general solution.

Comment: Ohh, well it's good that you explained the error from the question. But, this will still throw an error because of the extra characters that are sent with the response.