# getting value of request response object python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using python requests to validate mailgun email addresses.

```
def validateemail(emailaddress):
    return requests.get(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/address/validate",
        auth=("api", EMAILPUBLICVALIDATIONKEY ),
        params={'address': emailaddress}
    )

validation = validateemail(email)
validationtext = validation.json
```

validationtext contains the following response:

```
["{"address": "sdfhdd@assfuck.com", "did_you_mean": …: false, "is_role_address": false, "is_valid": tr", "ue, "mailbox_verification": "unknown", "parts": {"…: "assfuck.com", "local_part": "sdfhdd"}, "reason", "": null}"]
0: "{"address": "sdfhdd@assfuck.com", "did_you_mean": null, "is_disposable_address": false, "is_role_address": false, "is_valid": tr"
1: "ue, "mailbox_verification": "unknown", "parts": {"display_name": null, "domain": "assfuck.com", "local_part": "sdfhdd"}, "reason"
2: "": null}"
```

in array position 0 there is a `is_valid`property. I want to see if its true or not and do some action.

everything I have tried keeps giving me errors

```
print(validationtext[0].is_valid)
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

what gives?

Comment: The above `json` response is incomplete. Please post the compete json response.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877439/3091398). It should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validation.json` is a function, not an attribute.  If you want to get the result, you have to *call* the function by putting parentheses on the end, as in `validationtext = validation.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the `validate.json` function correctly. You're missing the parenthesis: `validate.json()`

Just a minor oversight on your end! Happens to the best of us.