# Convert response.text to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, django

I have an API which gives me the following data in response.text, How can I caonvert this data into a python dictionary?

response.text

```
[{"_id":"5dccedadff47e867a2833819","tel":"XXXX","loc":[28.498692,77.095215],"tripId":"5dccedaaff47e867a28337ec","mode":"automated","osm_data":{"distance_remained":10791,"time_remained":1649.5},"distance_remained":10870,"time_remained":1173,"curr_ETA":"2019-11-14T06:43:19.664Z","address":"100,
The National Media Centre, Sector 24, Gurugram, Haryana 122022,
India","city":"Gurugram","createdAt":"2019-11-14T06:01:17.166Z"},{"_id":"5dccedacff47e867a2833801","tel":"XXXX","loc":[28.498692,77.095215],"tripId":"5dccedaaff47e867a28337ec","mode":"automated","osm_data":{"distance_remained":10791,"time_remained":1649.5},"distance_remained":10870,"time_remained":1173,"curr_ETA":"2019-11-14T06:43:18.459Z","address":"100,
The National Media Centre, Sector 24, Gurugram, Haryana 122022,
India","city":"Gurugram","createdAt":"2019-11-14T06:01:16.163Z"}]
```

I wanto access the data in this response.text as a dictionary

Comment: `response.json` will give you a list of dicts, assuming the response is json-encoded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library)

Comment: This was a helpful question, upvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a JSON string. You can parse it with `json.loads()`

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(response.text)
```

Assuming the `response` you are referring comes from using the `requests` library, you can also simply do `response.json()`

Answer (score 1):

This is simple:

```
import json

resp_text = request.text

dict=json.loads(res_text)
```

this will convert your response text in to dictionary