# how to convert a python string to its original type after fetching from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have a field in database of type `longtext` with a value like 
`[{"A":"apple"}, {"B":"ball"} , {"c":"cat"}]` i.e a list of dictionaries. So now
I am fetching that from SQL database using `cursor.fetchone()` which returns a tuple with first element as my fetched field. so i extracted it by doing `(data,) = cursor.fetchone()`

but the problem is that now **data** returns a string while i need it to be a **list of dictionaries** as earlier. Please suggest some way through which i can get the value of my field from database as list of dictionaries

Comment: How did you create the string in the first place? Is it always going to be in JSON format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library) (The source of the JSON—a database or HTTP—doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `json` module as suggested in the comments, for example something like this should work:

```py
import json

long_text = '[{"A":"apple"}, {"B":"ball"} , {"c":"cat"}]'
list_of_dicts = json.loads(long_text)
print(list_of_dicts)

>>> [{'A': 'apple'}, {'B': 'ball'}, {'c': 'cat'}]
```