# Accessing API with python when API instrunctions show curl and I am using requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am attempting to access the random color palette option from this API using Python and requests
 http://colormind.io/api-access/

The API's instructions do not mention how to access with requests in Python.
I have tried several things and receive this message in Terminal when attempting to print the JSON.

```
bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
```

my code :

```
import requests as req
import json

def query():
    url = 'http://colormind.io/api/'
    response = req.get(url, data={"model":"default"}
    )
    print(response.json)


query()
```

when attempting to load the JSON or print JSON text it appears like it is an empty dictionary or list

what's happening here?

Comment: Hi fizzy, welcome to stack overflow. It seems you are making a bad call. You likely will want to read more on how to send that API a correct call. 

I would recommend running through an example like this one first, [Find Current Weather API](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-current-weather-of-any-city-using-openweathermap-api/)

Also, following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library) that URL is not returning valid JSON, instead its returning a  `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following code in terminal and received results.

```
import requests
data = '{"model":"default"}'
response = requests.post('http://colormind.io/api/', data=data)
response.json()

{'result': [[71, 94, 97], [109, 152, 137], [183, 213, 193], [243, 239, 204], [240, 153, 122]]}
```

Comment: Thank you this is working great. It looks like i was using requests.get instead of requests.post