# How to extract value from response.text() in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

```py
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://ftx.com/api/futures/ETH-PERP/stats"
response = requests.get(URL)
html=response.text
```

For the above code , i want to extract value of "nextFundingRate" from html. How should i do it?  Appreciate if any help.

[Reference Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omw55.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does This Solve Your Question?

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests


URL = "https://ftx.com/api/futures/ETH-PERP/stats"
response = requests.get(URL)
html = response.text

# SOLUTION
result = dict(json.loads(html))
print(result["result"]["nextFundingRate"])
```