# API data conversion in JSON and check validity

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I have a problem in the API formatted data. I am getting the data/API response from the besttime app in JSON. But when I copy that data in the `https://jsonlint.com/` it's showing it is invalid JSON. I also want to save the response as JSON in a local file.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://besttime.app/api/v1/forecasts"
# List with multiple venues in tuples
venue_list = [
("Simple Pleasures Cafe","3434 Balboa St, San Francisco, CA 94121, United States"),
]
for venue in venue_list:
    params = {
        'api_key_private': 'pri_e444ac582fsfg9fre4459909b7b753c5c45cbe6a',
        'venue_name': venue[0],
        'venue_address': venue[1]
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, params=params)
    print(response.json())
```

Please check the below JSON response I am getting

```
{'status': 'OK', 'epoch_analysis': '1627589243', 'venue_info': {'venue_id': 'ven_554f58764a45447a416b3152415968487956516f4264374a496843', 'venue_name': "Pasquale's Pizzeria", 'venue_address': '700 Irving St San Francisco, CA 94122 United States', 'venue_timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'venue_dwell_time_min': 20, 'venue_dwell_time_max': 20, 'venue_dwell_time_avg': 20, 'venue_type': 'RESTAURANT', 'venue_types': ['pizza_restaurant', 'italian_restaurant', 'meal_delivery']}, 'analysis': [{'day_info': {'day_int': 0, 'day_text': 'Monday', 'venue_open': 11, 'venue_closed': 0, 'day_rank_mean': 7, 'day_rank_max': 7, 'day_mean': 1, 'day_max': 3}, 'busy_hours': [], 'quiet_hours': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0], 'peak_hours': [], 'surge_hours': {'most_people_come': 15, 'most_people_leave': 18}, 'hour_analysis': [{'hour': 6, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 7, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 8, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 9, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 10, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 11, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 12, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 13, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 14, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 15, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 16, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 17, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 18, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 19, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 20, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 21, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 22, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 23, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 0, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 1, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 2, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 3, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 4, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 5, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}], 'day_raw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'day_info': {'day_int': 1, 'day_text': 'Tuesday', 'venue_open': 11, 'venue_closed': 0, 'day_rank_mean': 6, 'day_rank_max': 6, 'day_mean': 32, 'day_max': 52}, 'busy_hours': [12], 'quiet_hours': [21, 22, 23, 0], 'peak_hours': [{'peak_start': 11, 'peak_max': 12, 'peak_end': 18, 'peak_intensity': 3, 'peak_delta_mean_week': 17}], 'surge_hours': {'most_people_come': 11, 'most_people_leave': 20}, 'hour_analysis': [{'hour': 6, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 7, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 8, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 9, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 10, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 11, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 12, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 13, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 14, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 15, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 16, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 17, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 18, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 19, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 20, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 21, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 22, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 23, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 0, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 1, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 2, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 3, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 4, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 5, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}], 'day_raw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 50, 50, 40, 35, 35, 35, 35, 30, 20, 15, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'day_info': {'day_int': 2, 'day_text': 'Wednesday', 'venue_open': 11, 'venue_closed': 0, 'day_rank_mean': 2, 'day_rank_max': 3, 'day_mean': 44, 'day_max': 65}, 'busy_hours': [16, 17, 18, 19], 'quiet_hours': [23, 0], 'peak_hours': [{'peak_start': 11, 'peak_max': 17, 'peak_end': 21, 'peak_intensity': 3, 'peak_delta_mean_week': 30}], 'surge_hours': {'most_people_come': 11, 'most_people_leave': 20}, 'hour_analysis': [{'hour': 6, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 7, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 8, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 9, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 10, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 11, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 12, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 13, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 14, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 15, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 16, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 17, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 18, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 19, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 20, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 21, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 22, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 23, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 0, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 1, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 2, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 3, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 4, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 5, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}], 'day_raw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 45, 45, 45, 50, 55, 65, 65, 60, 45, 35, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'day_info': {'day_int': 3, 'day_text': 'Thursday', 'venue_open': 11, 'venue_closed': 0, 'day_rank_mean': 5, 'day_rank_max': 5, 'day_mean': 38, 'day_max': 56}, 'busy_hours': [14, 15, 16], 'quiet_hours': [22, 23, 0], 'peak_hours': [{'peak_start': 11, 'peak_max': 15, 'peak_end': 19, 'peak_intensity': 3, 'peak_delta_mean_week': 21}], 'surge_hours': {'most_people_come': 11, 'most_people_leave': 22}, 'hour_analysis': [{'hour': 6, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 7, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 8, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 9, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 10, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 11, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 12, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 13, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 14, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 15, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 16, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 17, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 18, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 19, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 20, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 21, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 22, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 23, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 0, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 1, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 2, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 3, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 4, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 5, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}], 'day_raw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 40, 50, 55, 55, 55, 50, 40, 35, 35, 30, 20, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'day_info': {'day_int': 4, 'day_text': 'Friday', 'venue_open': 11, 'venue_closed': 1, 'day_rank_mean': 2, 'day_rank_max': 2, 'day_mean': 44, 'day_max': 70}, 'busy_hours': [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 'quiet_hours': [23, 0, 1], 'peak_hours': [{'peak_start': 11, 'peak_max': 18, 'peak_end': 21, 'peak_intensity': 4, 'peak_delta_mean_week': 35}], 'surge_hours': {'most_people_come': 11, 'most_people_leave': 21}, 'hour_analysis': [{'hour': 6, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 7, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 8, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 9, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 10, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 11, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 12, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 13, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 14, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 15, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 16, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 17, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 18, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 19, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 20, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 21, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 22, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 23, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 0, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 1, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 2, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 3, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 4, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 5, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}], 'day_raw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 40, 45, 50, 50, 60, 65, 70, 65, 55, 40, 25, 15, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'day_info': {'day_int': 5, 'day_text': 'Saturday', 'venue_open': 11, 'venue_closed': 1, 'day_rank_mean': 3, 'day_rank_max': 1, 'day_mean': 43, 'day_max': 100}, 'busy_hours': [16, 17, 18, 19], 'quiet_hours': [22, 23, 0, 1], 'peak_hours': [{'peak_start': 11, 'peak_max': 17, 'peak_end': 21, 'peak_intensity': 5, 'peak_delta_mean_week': 65}], 'surge_hours': {'most_people_come': 16, 'most_people_leave': 18}, 'hour_analysis': [{'hour': 6, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 7, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 8, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 9, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 10, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 11, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 12, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 13, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 14, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 15, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 16, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 17, 'intensity_txt': 'High', 'intensity_nr': 2}, {'hour': 18, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 19, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 20, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 21, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 22, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 23, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 0, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 1, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 2, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 3, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 4, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 5, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}], 'day_raw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 40, 45, 45, 50, 75, 100, 65, 55, 50, 35, 15, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, {'day_info': {'day_int': 6, 'day_text': 'Sunday', 'venue_open': 11, 'venue_closed': 0, 'day_rank_mean': 4, 'day_rank_max': 4, 'day_mean': 42, 'day_max': 61}, 'busy_hours': [17, 18, 19], 'quiet_hours': [23, 0], 'peak_hours': [{'peak_start': 11, 'peak_max': 18, 'peak_end': 21, 'peak_intensity': 3, 'peak_delta_mean_week': 26}], 'surge_hours': {'most_people_come': 11, 'most_people_leave': 21}, 'hour_analysis': [{'hour': 6, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 7, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 8, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 9, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 10, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 11, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 12, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 13, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 14, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 15, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 16, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 17, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 18, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 19, 'intensity_txt': 'Above average', 'intensity_nr': 1}, {'hour': 20, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 21, 'intensity_txt': 'Average', 'intensity_nr': 0}, {'hour': 22, 'intensity_txt': 'Below average', 'intensity_nr': -1}, {'hour': 23, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 0, 'intensity_txt': 'Low', 'intensity_nr': -2}, {'hour': 1, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 2, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 3, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 4, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}, {'hour': 5, 'intensity_txt': 'Closed', 'intensity_nr': '999'}], 'day_raw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 45, 50, 45, 45, 50, 60, 60, 55, 45, 30, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}], 'api_key_private': 'pri_e444ac582f9f4909b7b753c5c45cbe6a'}

{'epoch': '1627589312', 'message': 'Error: Venue found, but could not forecast this venue. Potential issues: This place closed for the whole week, is too new, or not does not have enough volume (visitors) to make a forecast.', 'status': 'error', 'venue_info': {'venue_address': '1000a 3rd St San Francisco, CA 94158 United States', 'venue_name': 'Little Creatures Brewing Mission Bay'}}

{'epoch': '1627589315', 'message': 'Error: Venue found, but could not forecast this venue. Potential issues: This place closed for the whole week, is too new, or not does not have enough volume (visitors) to make a forecast.', 'status': 'error', 'venue_info': {'venue_address': '700 Post St San Francisco, CA 94109 United States', 'venue_name': 'Beyond Burma'}}
```

Comment: Yeah, your API key is visible

Comment: @Blupper Its fake key

Comment: Please put text into your question __as text__ not as pictures of text. Pictures of text are frankly useless.

Comment: Same as @balmy, if you could provide us with the JSON, maybe through a pastebin, that would make this easier to solve

Comment: Please put a representative __minimal__ sample fof your JSON into the question as text. Links to important details like this json can go absent after a while rendering your question of zero value to StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add json. Please check now. Thank you

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ is correct.  As per both [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7) and the [original JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), *A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in **double quotes**, using backslash escapes.*  Your strings are single-quoted.  Also your JSON shows three root containers whereas a well-formed JSON document should have only one root.

Comment: It looks  as if you're printing the Python representation of a dictionary, rather than actually printing out JSON.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library) - `response.json()` has already decoded the JSON string into a Python object for you.

Comment: Formatted your JSON since the question was total mess. Just wondering is it JSON because it wasn't valid. You have multiple roots and identifiers didn't have `"`.

Comment: @JamesZ The data shown *wasn't* JSON. You shouldn't have changed it, as it was actually the problem this question is about. `response.json()` doesn't return the received JSON string, instead it parses it and returns the parsed Python data structure.

Answer (score 0):

To save the response to a local file:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://besttime.app/api/v1/forecasts"
# List with multiple venues in tuples
venue_list = [
("Simple Pleasures Cafe","3434 Balboa St, San Francisco, CA 94121, United States"),
]
for venue in venue_list:
    params = {
        'api_key_private': 'pri_e444ac582fsfg9fre4459909b7b753c5c45cbe6a',
        'venue_name': venue[0],
        'venue_address': venue[1]
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, params=params, stream=True)
    
    #To save the response to a local file
    filename = "response.json"
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
      for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
         fd.write(chunk)
```

To answer your error in jsonlint.com, as suggested by others in the comments, you seem to be printing the python `dict` equivalent and trying to paste it in jsonlint.com

Since it is not a vaild JSON, it is throwing error.

Try the above snippet. After the file is generated, take data from the file and try it in jsonlint.com

You can skip the `stream=True` if your response is small in size. Then you don't need the `for` loop. Simply write `fd.write(respone.text)` inside the `with`

Note: Due to some constraints, I didn't execute the above snippet. It is purely based on my knowledge and assumption. I request the community to make changes if necessary