# Python grab "next" url in response

Tags: python

Needed simple help for a beginner :)
Below the python code:

```
url = "theurl"
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-auth-Token': 'thetoken'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_data = response.json()
nexturl = json_data['next']
```

Below the response from the request:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 112,
        "name": "sample",
        "type": "sample",
        "sku": "SKUF46386",
        "description": "",
        "weight": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "depth": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "price": 162,
        "cost_price": 0,
        "retail_price": 0,
        "sale_price": 0,
        "map_price": 0,
        "tax_class_id": 0,
        "product_tax_code": "",
        "calculated_price": 162,
        "categories": [
            25
        ]
],
"meta": {
    "pagination": {
        "total": 14526,
        "count": 50,
        "per_page": 50,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 291,
        "links": {
            "next": "?page=2&limit=50",
            "current": "?page=1&limit=50"
        },
        "too_many": false
    }
}
```

}

How to grab this value: meta.pagination.links.next and store it within a new variable. When I try to run the code the Idle comes with a message: KeyError: 'next'

Comment: `x = entry["meta"]["pagination"]["links"]["next"]` ...

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68500453/3357352

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library)

Comment: you can do a loop where `links.next` is true.

Comment: thnx, this works.

x = entry["meta"]["pagination"]["links"]["next"] works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` is a dictionary. To get a value for a specified key from a dictionary, you need to: `your_dict['key']`.

In your case, there is a `response` dictionary with two keys: `"data"` and `"meta"`. So to get value (also a dictionary) for the `"meta"` key, you have to: `response["meta"].

The value you're looking for (for key `"next"`) is stored deeper - in the dictionary you've just got with the `"meta"` key, there is a `"pagination"` key, whose value is another dictionary with a key `"links"`, whose value is *again* another dictionary with the *wanted* key `"next"`.
So, to get the value for the `"next"` key you have to:

```py
response["meta"]["pagination"]["links"]["next"]`
```